# How to use regular expression in HTML By id in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ssn_button_5")).click();
assertEquals("999-99-null", driver.findElement(By.id("ssn_display_5")).getText());
```

This is my the ssn button and the ssn display digit is change dynamically.

Where can I use regular expression use and how can I write the code please give step by step

Comment: Please describe your problem in more details. What you want? Find element using regexp?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it the next way using xpath function `By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'ssn_display')]")`